# Use same ddrmenu across child portals in dnn

Tags: dotnetnuke

Our site have a parent portal and many child portals all of which share the same main menu navigation.

We've constructed the menu using ddrmenu however don't know how the same menu can be shown in child portals.

At the moment I'm stumped and think that we would have to use a static menu. Is there no dynamic way.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want the same menu structure in all the child portals based on the parent, so if you add a page in the parent called 'Page 2' it will also appear in the menu structures of the children.

If you want what I wrote above this is not possible. By design the child portals are treated as separate entities with their own menu structure, content, users etc. If you want this you have to make a static menu as you already suggested or write your own module\skin object. Perhaps an some kind of JQuery\Ajax solution could also work?